# How to check if browser supports rollovers (ie many mobile devices do not have a cursor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a way of checking whether rollover events will work for navigation, and if not I am going to switch these to click events.

I have been looking through jQuery.Support and Modernizr but haven't found anything specific, closest I found was Modernizr's touch, but doesn't seem to be exactly what I need.

What is the best way of checking this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid the question entirely: ***just do both***.

Include `:hover` rules where you want rollover navigation, and those rules may or may not ever get applied. You don't have to care.

Meanwhile, with JavaScript, write a `$('.foo').click(function() { $(this).addClass('hover'); }` setup, so you can also apply `.hover` rules in the same stylesheet. Mine normally end up being `:hover, .hover` rules so they're actually completely identical.

This doubling up means that someone using a mouse may also click. This is redundant, but not harmful.

Comment: I like it. It's also worth mentioning that some mobile devices simulate cursor hover by pressing and holding on an element, but I imagine many users wouldn't expect they need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigator object to identify a browser. Check user-agent and platform on which browser is running and then accordingly customize your webpage for mobile devices.

You can use something like this:

var ismobile=navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i)

Comment: Checking for specific user agents almost always causes more problems than it solves. You can't capture future products (you failed to check for the iJumbo device that hasn't been invented yet), and may overlook existing products (Windows XP running on a tablet). Checking for feature support is preferable.

Comment: Yeah. I get it now. Your solution is also more maintainable.